# RSSI range for WiFi icons

Tags: wi-fi, stock-android, notification-bar, notification-icons, network-signal

What is stock RSSI range for the WiFi indicator icon in notification bar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't look back through older versions, but here's information accurate as of Android 7.1.2.

The code that performs the transformation from RSSI to signal "level" is found in the [`WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel`](https://github.com/eldarerathis/android_frameworks_base/blob/eldarerathis-7.1.x/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#L1530) method:

```
public static int calculateSignalLevel(int rssi, int numLevels) {
    if (rssi <= MIN_RSSI) {
        return 0;
    } else if (rssi >= MAX_RSSI) {
        return numLevels - 1;
    } else {
        float inputRange = (MAX_RSSI - MIN_RSSI);
        float outputRange = (numLevels - 1);
        return (int)((float)(rssi - MIN_RSSI) * outputRange / inputRange);
    }
}
```

...where `MIN_RSSI` is -100 and `MAX_RSSI` is -55 ([source](https://github.com/eldarerathis/android_frameworks_base/blob/eldarerathis-7.1.x/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#L633)). The input range is "dynamic" in the sense that its based off of how many resource files are available for the WiFi icon, but in AOSP this value will be 5 because it has icons for 0-4 bars. Using the above logic and values, the ranges come out to approximately:

- -55 or higher: 4 bars
- -56 to -66: 3 bars
- -67 to -77: 2 bars
- -78 to -88: 1 bar
- -89 or lower: 0 bars